# Convert json string to .net object array

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

I am trying to convert a json string (content) response

to parse into Attachment [] object using

```
Attachment attachment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Attachment>(content);
```

Question: How do I turn it into an Attachment [] object array?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: And? Did it work? Did it not? If not, what's the error?

Comment: Its not working.  How do I turn it into an Attachment [] object array?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ this site will generate a proper C# Class for you .

Answer (score 2):

Your `Attachment` object doesn't quite reflect the data structure of the response. Create an AttachmentCollection to contain the array of attachments:

```
public class AttachmentCollection
{
    public List<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize as an `AttachmentCollection`:

```
var attachments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttachmentCollection>(content);
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this into IEnumerable so that the content can be passed by WebApi.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you trying to return this data in a response?

Comment: Yes since I'm getting that json from another web service and want to parse it and then resend it as json response so it can be read using Angularjs

Comment: In that case it's not necessary to distinguish between a List/IEnumerable. The JSON serializer will convert both to a JSON array.

Comment: getting content = client.DownloadString(url);

Comment: What error do you get? (Btw, the custom on StackOverflow is to provide as much error info as you can upfront when something isn't working.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list(Collection) for that.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good point about the List -- in retrospect I think JsonConvert needs a concrete type instead of an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON.Net

What you need to do is first get the JSONArray and do a for statement for each JSONObject in the JSON Array. In the for statement you could use Linq to create a list of your custom Attachement class. See below:

```
List<Attachment> AttachmentList = new List<Attachment>();
JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
    Attachment newAttachment = new Attachment
    {
       WriteUpID = (int)o["WriteUpID"],
       InitialScanID = (int)o["InitialScanID"],
       //etc, do this for all Class items. 
    }
    AttachmentList.Add(newAttachment);
}
//Then change the AttachmentList to an array when you're done adding Attachments
Attachment[] attachmentArray = AttachmentList.ToArray();
```

Voila

Comment: [JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.]